# Is it possible to save maple 13 file so that svn would recognize it as a text file?

Tags: svn, text, maple

So I want to share some of my maple code files with world. I would like to use google code svn for it. But as far as I know maple saves files not in a source/text way.
So is it possible to save maple 13 file so that svn would recognize it as a text file and it would be registered so that when you download it and double click on it it would open in maple for everyone who installed maple?

And does any one share maple throe google code anyway?

Comment: You can store binary files in SVN too. You just can not do easy diff/merge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some people write their Maple code in plaintext files. The filename extension ".mpl" is a popular choice for such source files. They can be accessed from the Maple interface (eg. GUI) using the `read` command.

If you have code inside a Worksheet, then you can often/sometimes get it to a plaintext source file by using the Standard GUI menubar's File->Export As.. action. In the pop-up filemanager, select "Maple Input (.mpl)" in the "Files of type:" drop-down menu below the File name entry field.

This method can export code written normally, in the main sheet, but it doesn't seem to export code that is hidden inside GUI Components, Code Edit Regions, Start-up section.

For your purpose, don't "Export As.." from a a Worksheet to either "Maple text (.txt)" or "Plain text (.txt)" since doing so adds the Maple input prompt to the start of each line. The "Maple input (.mpl)" export, on the other hand, should produce somethign that can be read directly as valid code input.

Comment: i came here googling because i have the same question. i already experimented with .mpl export, but i found no way to make a worksheet out if it afterwards. it seems like maple opens these files in word processor mode or something. so how do you get it "red" again?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand maple uses a plain text format for typical source files, they just have another file extension. Just put them in SVN and you should be fine.